# [Iphone]How to get the length of one text string under one specific font with no word wrap

Tags: iphone

Hi I am new as a Iphone developer.
I am wondering how to get the length of a given string under one specific UIFont, WITHOUT line word wrap.

say I have a NSString* lpText = @"a unknon lenght string .....  string" //could be very long 
and I am using the "Times New Rome" font for rendering...

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This should work (untested):

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Set the font you need.  The line break mode shouldn't matter here.

Answer (score 3):

Look up the UIKit additions to NSString:

- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
  Returns the size of the string if it were to be rendered with the specified font on a single line.
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
  Returns the size of the string if it were rendered and constrained to the specified size.
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode

Returns the size of the string if it were rendered with the specified constraints.